# RoR, Paperclip and S3 upload image error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I deployed my rails app and I used S3 to host images that I will be uploading using paperclip. Here is the error that I keep getting even though I did permit :photo in my controller params

```
2015-12-08T13:40:00.439949+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 403 0.042095 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"customlized",:content_length=>30237,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: shanab.jpg,:key=>"products/photos/000/000/009/original/shanab.jpg") AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied
2015-12-08T13:40:00.439953+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-08T13:40:00.441272+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
2015-12-08T13:40:00.442792+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-08T13:40:00.442793+00:00 app[web.1]: AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied):
2015-12-08T13:40:00.442794+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:35:in `block in create'
2015-12-08T13:40:00.442795+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:34:in `create'
```

My production.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
 :storage => :s3,
 :s3_credentials => {
   :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
   :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
   :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
   }
}
```

I did config it on Heroku to what S3 gave me as credentials

My product.rb

```
has_attached_file :photo ,
        :storage => :s3,
        :s3_credentials => Proc.new{|a| a.instance.s3_credentials },
                    styles: { medium: '300x300>', thumb: '100x100>' }

def s3_credentials
   {:bucket => "Deleted", :access_key_id => "Deleted", :secret_access_key => "Deleted"}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your AWS credentials out of your `paperclip_defaults` and the `product.rb` model, and add to an `aws.yml` file in the `config` directory:

```
production:
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
```

(also make sure you have `gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.6'` in your Gemfile)

More documentation on S3 with Paperclip here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3